# MySQL / PHP Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that is used for connecting recipe ingredients to each recipe by using right join, an excerpt of the table is detailed below:-

```
| Connection ID | RecipeID | IngredientID
__________________________________________
| 1         | 1    | 358
| 2         | 1    | 293
| 3         | 1    | 137
| 4         | 2    | 158
| 5         | 2    | 94
| 6         | 2    | 359
| 7         | 2    | 360
| 8         | 2    | 366
| 9         | 3    | 361
| 10        | 3    | 362
| 11        | 3    | 25
| 12        | 3    | 10
| 13        | 4    | 363
| 14        | 4    | 364
| 15        | 4    | 365
| 16        | 4    | 355
| 17        | 4    | 366
```

Using the above example table, I am attempting to create a query that will search which RecipeID has ingredients (Using the IngredientID) added by the user, showing only recipes that the user can make with ingredients in hand, ie not showing recipes the user cannot make.

I am relatively new to PHP/MySQL and would be grateful for any recommendation on methodology to use in order to return the desired.

(If it assists the methodology, the recipe with most ingredients is 16, there are also 56,469 rows in the above example table).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide some expect result?

Comment: I cannot see that this is a duplicate question, and have reviewed multiple threads that have give no indication as to a method for this task. An example would be a query search where RecipeID includes 358, 293, 137 would return RecipeID 1 (and possibly many others), if there was to be a query RecipeID 358,137 it would not return RecipeID as the user does not have all the required IngredientID's.

Comment: I agree that this duplicate is insufficient for OP's requirements. Every ingredient in the returned recipe must be in the input list. It can be a smaller subset of the list (making both Gordon and Barmar's answer insufficient). Consider the input list `(358,293,137,158,94)` which should return recipe 1.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL 
You could use a query as this

```
select RecipeID  
from my_table  
where IngredentID in (358,293)
having count(distinct IngredientID) = 2 
group by RecipeID
```

where you pass  the TngredentID  as  IN condition for filter the rows and filtering the candidate  rows with  RecipeID  that have a number of ingredients equals to the number of ingredients you passed  in the IN clause

Comment: Thank you, I have attempted the provided method, which does not appear to return any results. How scale-able would this be? A user could potentially have up to 2500 different IngredientID's to search against the excerpted table above, which contains 56,469 rows.

Comment: with proper index..  is not a problem  .. 50k - 60k rows  are very few for a database ..  ..

Comment: `HAVING Count(IngredientID) = (SELECT Count(Distinct IngredientID) FROM my_table WHERE IngredientID = mainqueryalias.IngredientID)` is a bit more verbose but would solve the problem where the count of ingredients matching the user input for the recipe return matches the count of all ingredients needed for the recipe.

Comment: @JNevill  .. the suggestion is interesting  ..but how the query can get the number of ingredient entered  by the user  .. ?  is not clear to me

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. User enters a big long list of ingredients they have in their cupboards. Recipes returned have to be complete and contain only items in the list. Multiple recipes can be returned. As I wrote in the above comments: Consider the input list (358,293,137,158,94) which should return recipe 1. Recipe 1 contains the first three ingredients in the list of 5, and those three ingredients are all of the ingredients in recipe 1.

Comment: I have found a solution of which is to be fully tested, would be grateful for any comments if you see a more efficient method!SELECT ConnectionID, RecipeID, IngredientID, RecipeName, TotalIngredients, COUNT(*)  
FROM Connections
LEFT JOIN Recipes
USING (RecipeID)
WHERE IngredientID in (358,293,137,276,1,8,177,366)
GROUP BY RecipeID
HAVING COUNT(*) = TotalIngredients